# How to Update adobe air native menu?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe

How can I update my native menu's in adobe air application listening to the on select event? For example when the system loads, the app will show "Sign in" option. When the user clicks it and signs in how can I change the menu to "Sign Out" ?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to change the menu text dynamically..
Just change the text propert of the link

[image]

Comment: sorry, I didnt understood what exactly you mean. I am trying to develop a gmail notifier like system. In this app, once you sign in, the menu name gets changed. how to do it?